# Calling a c function from lua 5.2 generates a syntax error

Tags: c++, c, lua

I've been trying to get lua scripting working for a small game I'm working on, but lua seems to be more trouble than its worth. After much googling and hair tearing, I managed to get simple scripts running but quickly hit a wall. C functions don't seem to want to bind to lua, or at least don't want to run after binding. g++ compiles the c code without incident but the lua interpreter generates this syntax error:

```
LUA ERROR: bin/lua/main.lua:1: syntax error near 'getVersion'
```

My C(++) code:

```
#include <lua.hpp>

static const luaL_Reg lualibs[] = 
{
    {"base", luaopen_base},
    {"io", luaopen_io},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

void initLua(lua_State* state);
int getVersion(lua_State* state);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    lua_State* state = luaL_newstate();
    initLua(state);

    lua_register(state, "getVersion", getVersion);

    int status = luaL_loadfile(state, "bin/lua/main.lua");
    if(status == LUA_OK){
        lua_pcall(state, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
    }else{
        fprintf(stderr, "LUA ERROR: %s\n", lua_tostring(state, -1));
        lua_close(state);
        return -1;
    }

    lua_close(state);
    return 0;
}

void initLua(lua_State* state)
{
    const luaL_Reg* lib = lualibs;
    for (; lib->func != NULL; lib ++)
    {
        luaL_requiref(state, lib->name, lib->func, 1);
        lua_settop(state, 0);
    };
    delete lib;
}
int getVersion(lua_State* state)
{
    lua_pushnumber(state, 1);
    return 1;
};
```

The Lua code:

```
print getVersion()
```

Comment: `print(getVersion())`

Comment: @H2CO3: I do believe that's the answer; you should post it. (No, I'm not stalking you!)

Comment: @KeithThompson I just did :)

Comment: @KeithThompson You know what's funny? I don't speak Lua. I found the answer by trying some common sense (~5 sec), then I found the exact precise explanation by googling "lua function string parentheses", and it was in the official docs (4th hit, ~1 minute).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`print` is a function. Since its argument is neither a table constructor nor a string literal, you have to call it using `()`:

```
print(getVersion())
```

[Read the funny manual here.](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.html)

Comment: Wow, I've been struggling with this for hours, assuming it was my fault in the c code... It's still my fault, only with poor lua code instead. EDIT: Can't mark this as the answer yet, but will do so when I can.

Comment: @DelishusCake [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114949/calling-a-c-function-from-lua-5-2-generates-a-syntax-error/18115006#comment26523234_18114949) - Google, 4th hit :)